# Taking an element off the stack each method call

Tags: c#, stack

I have a question considering a program that stimulates a stack (not using any built-in stack features or such).

```
stack2= 1 2 3 4 5 //single dimension array of 5 elements
```

By calling the method `pop` the stack should look like the following, basically taking an element off each time the stack is being called up again.

```
stack2= 1 2 3 4 0  
stack2= 1 2 3 0 0  
stack2= 1 2 0 0 0  
stack2= 1 0 0 0 0  
stack2= 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
    number= TryPop(s2);
    //use number
    ShowStack(s2, "s2");
}

public void Push(int g)
{
    if (top == Max)
    {
        throw new Exception("Stack overflow...");
    }
    else
    {
        tabel[top] = g;
        top++;
    }
}/*Push*/
```

I already have code that fills my array with values (through a push method). The pop method should take the last value and place it on 0, then calls up the next stack and place the following on 0 (like shown above in stack2).

The current pop method that keeps track of the top index (0 elements = 0 top, 1 element = 1 top etc..) already includes an underflow warning if this goes on 0 or below (which is correct).

```
public int Pop()
{
    if(top <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Stack underflow...");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = tabel.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)  
        {
            //...Really not sure what to do here.
        }
    }

    return number; 

}/*Pop*/
```

Since in the other class I already have a loop (`for` loop shown above) that simulates 6 times the s2 stack.  (first stack: 1 2 3 4 0, second stack 1 2 3 0 0 and so on.)
How exactly do I take an element off each time? Either I have the entire display on 0 or the 0 in the wrong places / out of index errors.

Edit: Working Pop method:

```
public int Pop()
{
    if(top <= 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Stack underflow...");
    }

    top--;
    tabel[top] = 0;
    number = tabel[top];

    return number;
}/*Pop*/
```

Comment: Can you show us your Push implementation? Why do you think do you need a loop in the Pop method?

Comment: When using top to Pop, watch out for off-by-one errors, since it's indexed one element past the top item on the stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To implement a stack, you need an array and a "pointer" to the top of the stack.

```
empty       _ _ _ _ _
            ↑
```

In your code, `table` is the array and `top` is the pointer (as array index).

**Push**

To push an item to a stack, put the item at top of the stack and advance the pointer by one:

```
push 1      1 _ _ _ _
              ↑

push 2      1 2 _ _ _
                ↑

push 3      1 2 3 _ _
                  ↑
```

That's what your code already does:

```
table[top] = g;    // insert `g` at `top` into `table`
top++;             // advance `top` by one
```

**Pop**

To pop an item, move the pointer back by one and return+erase the item at the top:

```
pop 3       1 2 _ _ _
                ↑

pop 2       1 _ _ _ _
              ↑

pop 1       _ _ _ _ _
            ↑
```

Now try to translate your solution for Push to do the reverse as shown here!

Comment: Cheers for the well drawed illustration.
The thing is i fail to adress because my Push is a void method. Where my pop has to be a int with a single return type. The push value uses a specifiek number to push on it, but how exactly do i call upon this value(index)? table[top] = // everything results in out of index.

Comment: @Sef: Please focus on this: "Move the pointer back by one and return the item at the top". Can you try to implement this and post your solution?

Comment: Cheers for all the input!. Placed the code in the op at the bottom.
My problem was i was placing the top-- in the wrong order, resulting in out of index errors all the time.
Perhaps another small question. I had to use a stringbuider to be able to show me the desired results (else i get the class name and thats it). Is there any other way exept for the stringbuilder to acheive this? Have not really seen this, and perhaps i should not have used this already.   Anyway thanks a bunch, very much apperciated!

Comment: @Sef: I'm not going to answer your second question here because it is not directly related to this question, and also comments are not appropriate or convenient for answering questions for a number of reasons (voting, formatting, character limits, etc, etc). You are welcome to create a new question though.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a local variable `result` and set it to the current value of the top of the stack, using `top` as an index into your data. Then decrement your `top` variable and return `result`. Since it is homework I won't post the code - you should try to implement it yourself to make sure that you understand it.

There is no need to loop to implement `Pop`. There is also no need to zero values as you remove them, although you can do this if you wish.

You should also note that this implementation is not thread-safe. That is OK, but make sure that this is clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a `for` loop in `Pop()`. You are only removing one element, and you know the location of that element (it's at index `top`), so you need only deal with that element of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that top references the top of the stack, setting the value at the top of your stack to 0 and decrementing the top should be sufficient.

```
public int Pop()
{
    if(top < 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Stack underflow...");
    }
    else
    {
        table[top] = 0;
        top--;
    }

    // not sure where number comes from
    return number; 

}/*Pop*/
```

Comment: Hello,   Yes the top shows how many items there are currently in the stack (top 5 for a full stack of 5 elements).
Although every time i try anything (also with the code above) i get out of index errors. Cheers.

Comment: @Sef, you probably have to post your complete code then.

Your top might be pointing out of the array. Assuming that your stack is an array of 5 integers, top is valid if it's 0 (first element) to 4 (last element). Anything otherwise will throw out of bounds exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure i'm going to get flamed for giving him the answer but i know what i would want if i were in his shoes on a Sunday. I hope dtb's answer gets the most upvotes because it deserves it for an excellent explanation of a stack!

Here is a basic example of a stack. Please learn it. don't just paste it in your homework.

```
public class Stack<T>
{
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    private int _CurrentPosition;
    private T[] _Values;

    public Stack(int capacity)
    {
        _CurrentPosition = -1;
        _Values = new T[capacity];
        Count = capacity;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        if (_CurrentPosition < 0)
            return default(T);

        return _Values[_CurrentPosition];
    }

    public void Push(T item)
    {
        if (_CurrentPosition == Count)
            throw new Exception("Stack overflow...");

        _CurrentPosition++;
        _Values[_CurrentPosition] = item;
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        if(_CurrentPosition < 0)
            throw new Exception("Stack underflow...");
        T item = _Values[_CurrentPosition];
        _Values[_CurrentPosition] = default(T);
        _CurrentPosition--;
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: <generic flame for posting full solution to homework question>. Please remove it.

Comment: We have to be sensitive to homework etiquette? God forbid he goes to another site that has code examples. LOL I Love the "<generic flame...>"